Is it possible to compile SCSS to the CSS that is only used on the website (external css) or page (internal css)?
I normally build sites in either Next.js with external CSS files (Next.js does the compiling from external SCSS files to the CSS files), or static/CMS based sites/modules/plugins also with external CSS files (in this case Gulp does the compiling from SCSS to the CSS files).
With this approach, a page or even the whole site will have all CSS included on all pages, used or not which adds to page size of course
I have a "base" framework I created myself to include on my projects. My base framework would have lots of styles like the following so I can pick which class I want for a particular browser width (mobile first approach):
.hide { display: none; }
@media (min-width: $vsmall) { .hide-vsmall  { display: none; } }
@media (min-width: $small)  { .hide-small   { display: none; } }
@media (min-width: $medium) { .hide-medium  { display: none; } }
@media (min-width: $large)  { .hide-large   { display: none; } }
@media (min-width: $vlarge) { .hide-vlarge  { display: none; } }

I would then use a class like this then which would hide this content on my medium breakpoint and above:
<div class="hide-medium">My content</div>

I have many styles like the above so the problem is it would all be included on all pages, the whole site, whereas I may just want to use just one of the above on one page, .hide-medium on one page only. So I would not be using the others, and not be using any on other pages, yet they will be compiled into the external CSS.
I do not have to use external stylesheets. This is just because I am old school and back in the day it was considered internal and inline styles were bad. I think this may have changed, but I am not sure as I have not looked into it. So if internal CSS is OK these days then I am fine to switch to that.
If internal CSS is OK, then it still has the problem of how to only add the used CSS from the base SCSS files to the internal pages.
I prefer not to use inline styling at all, but again, if its fine these days and there is an easy way to do it then fine.
One reason I use my own frameworks is because I only have classnames I know I may use. If I used Bootstrap or similar I assume their base CSS files would be included which are so much larger than mine. But again, maybe this has changed now.
So the question is, are there any ways to compile only the whole site used SCSS into the external files or page specific CSS to internal (if internal is considered to be OK)?
Thanks

You can use tools like PurifyCSS or UnCSS.
These tools analyze your HTML files and extract only the CSS selectors that are being used. Any unused CSS is removed.
But a little site note:
Bootstrap CSS isn't that big anymore. There is a minified version which will not drive you into performance issues.

thanks, do they integrate with Gulp and so can remove the unused CSS before Gulp creates the CSS files? Can they also plugin to Next.js do you know? Not sure how Next.js CSS compiles works as I dont run gulp for it, its built in.
Re. BootStrap there will still be like 90% of css we dont use. If I can get above working, then I guess I can use it for any CSS framework and so can consider bootstrap then or another then. I create my own because then that 90% is actually being used and maybe 10% not! (completely ballpark percentages just to demonstrate the point!).

I am being quite lazy there I am sure I can search those up to find out from here. Thanks.
